# Wrong shape 'logits' and 'labels'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

When executing the following code:

```
# Set the input shape and number of classes
INPUT_SHAPE = (128, 128, 3)  # Assume 128x128 RGB images
NUM_CLASSES = 2  # Food or not food

# Set the batch size
BATCH_SIZE = 64

# Set the directory containing the images
image_dir = 'food_images_2'

# Create an ImageDataGenerator object
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)

# Use the generator to load the images from the directory
train_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(image_dir,
                                                     target_size=(128, 128),
                                                     color_mode='rgb',
                                                     class_mode='binary',
                                                     batch_size=64,
                                                     subset='training')
val_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(image_dir,
                                                   target_size=(128, 128),
                                                   color_mode='rgb',
                                                   class_mode='binary',
                                                   batch_size=64,
                                                   subset='validation')

# Get the images and labels from the generator
x_train, y_train = next(train_data_gen)
x_val, y_val = next(val_data_gen)


# Define the encoder
encoder_input = layers.Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE)
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_input)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoder_output = layers.MaxPooling2D(2, padding='same')(x)

# Define the decoder
decoder_input = encoder_output
x = layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_input)
x = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)
decoder_output = layers.Conv2D(3, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

# Define the autoencoder
autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(encoder_input, decoder_output)

# Define the encoder model
encoder = tf.keras.Model(encoder_input, encoder_output)

# Compile the autoencoder with a loss function and an optimizer
autoencoder.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')


from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

NUM_EPOCHS = 10

# Create a ModelCheckpoint callback
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint('autoencoder_weights.h5', save_weights_only=True, period=5)

# Fit the autoencoder to the training data, using the ModelCheckpoint callback
history = autoencoder.fit(x_train,
                          x_train,
                          epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                          validation_data=(x_val, x_val),
                          callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
```

The `autoencoder.fit()` function throws an error telling me:

```
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((64, 124, 124, 3) vs (64, 128, 128, 3)).
```

The output of

```
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_val.shape)
print(y_val.shape)
```

results in:

```
(64, 128, 128, 3)
(64,)
(64, 128, 128, 3)
(64,)
```

And the summary of the encoder gives me the following information:

```
________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_17 (InputLayer)       [(None, 128, 128, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_79 (Conv2D)          (None, 128, 128, 16)      448       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_39 (MaxPoolin  (None, 64, 64, 16)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_80 (Conv2D)          (None, 64, 64, 8)         1160      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_40 (MaxPoolin  (None, 32, 32, 8)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_81 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 8)         584       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_41 (MaxPoolin  (None, 16, 16, 8)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_82 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 8)         584       
                                                                 
 up_sampling2d_30 (UpSamplin  (None, 32, 32, 8)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
...
Total params: 4,963
Trainable params: 4,963
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I have no clue where the (64, **124**,**124**, 3) is coming from. I do believe this issue could be solved quite easily but i've been searching for hours and unfortunately without succes. All help is welcome!

Comment: mismatch is from the decoder layers, add padding `same` in decoder layer `x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)`

Comment: @V.M Thanks a lot man! Stupid oversight of me...